# mysql select a certain range using autoincrement ID

Tags: mysql, select

I need to select a certain range of a table, say #1000~5000 using the auto increment ID.
What should the syntax be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE columnID BETWEEN 1000 and 5000`

Comment: so the auto increment column is 'columnID'? I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: You should be renaming the columns to match the ones in your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000
```